# Thumbnail Cloud Function fails with "Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, rmdir '/tmp/thumbs' at Error (native)"

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

My Firebase Cloud Function fails with the following error:

```
Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, rmdir '/tmp/thumbs' at Error (native)
```

With my function I create thumbnails for uploaded pictures and save them to Firebase Storage. The way I built the below code everything works fine (with the exception that every function call fails). But I fear that since old files in the tmp folder are not deleted my tmp folder will fill up with unnecessary files.

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'

import {tmpdir} from 'os'
import {join, dirname} from 'path'

import * as sharp from 'sharp'
import * as fs from 'fs-extra'
import * as admin from "firebase-admin"

const storage = admin.storage()

/* Saves thumbnails for all userPics uploaded to Google Cloud Storage */
export const thumbnailCreator = functions.storage
    .object()
    .onFinalize(async object => {
        const bucket = storage.bucket(object.bucket)
        const filePath = object.name
        const fileName = filePath.split('/').pop()
        const bucketDir = dirname(filePath)
        const workingDir = join(tmpdir(), 'thumbs')

        /* Temporary: Creates a random number for the sourceFilePath
        * because currently bucket.file(filePath).download does not seem to overwrite
        * existing files and fs.rmdir(workingDir) does throw that error... */

        const randomNr = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15) +
            Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15)

        const tmpFilePath = join(workingDir, `source_${randomNr}.png`)

        if (!object.contentType.includes('image')) {
            console.log('exiting function (no image)')
            return false
        }

        if (fileName.includes('thumb@')) {
            console.log('exiting function (already a thumbnail')
            return false
        }

        // 1. Ensure thumbnail dir exists
        await fs.ensureDir(workingDir)

        // 2. Download Source File
        await bucket.file(filePath).download({
            destination: tmpFilePath
        })

        // 3. Resize the images and define an array of upload promises
        const sizes = [64, 128, 256, 512]

        const uploadPromises = sizes.map(async size => {
            const thumbName = `thumb@${size}_${fileName}`
            const thumbPath = join(workingDir, thumbName)

            // Resize source image
            await sharp(tmpFilePath)
                .rotate()
                .resize(size, size)
                .toFile(thumbPath)

            // Upload to GCS
            const file = await bucket.upload(thumbPath, {
                destination: join(bucketDir, thumbName),
                predefinedAcl: 'publicRead'
            })

        })

        // 4. Run the upload operations
        await Promise.all(uploadPromises)

        // 5. Cleanup remove the tmp/thumbs from the filesystem
        return fs.rmdir(workingDir)
        // TODO: This fails every time -> also tried with fs.remove(workingDir), same issue.

    })
```

As you can see, the way I handle it is by giving a GUID to the filename of the source.png, because when the function is called next time it would not overwrite the already downloaded file when doing `bucket.file(filePath).download()`.

But I would like to clean my tmp folder and I cannot figure out why the folder is "busy or locked". Is there a way to unlock it before trying to delete it?

**UPDATE - SOLUTION FROM DOUG**

As Doug answered below, deleting all the files before deleting the folder worked. So I ended up doing this:

```
// 5. Cleanup remove the tmp/thumbs from the filesystem
await fs.emptyDir(workingDir)
await fs.remove(workingDir)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this would cause EBUSY, but rmdir (both node's version, and the unix command line of the same name) requires that the directory be empty before calling it.  You've left files in there, which would probably cause rmdir to fail.  Try deleting each generated file individually, then deleting the directory afterward.

Comment: Thx Doug, that helped! I forgot to mention above that I already tried it with fs-extra's `fs.remove()` which should delete folder with files in them, but mysteriously the same error happened. Now deleting the files first with `fs.emptyDir(workingDir)` and only then deleting the dir with `fs.remove(workingDir)` works fine. I knew I could trust your pizaz ;-)